# T-SQL Conversion Errors and WHERE...NOT IN

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

We are joining a `varchar(15)` Head of Household to an integer Member ID. In the past, this has never thrown an error because the characters in the Head of Household field were always numeric. We've recently introduced some test cases which follow the pattern 'QESUB' + up to ten digits. These test cases need to be filtered out of any processing.

The following SQL successfully filters out the test cases. However, when a new test case is added, we need to go in and add a new value to the hardcoded list of exclusions in the NOT IN clause.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
    m.headofhouse,
    mx.MemberID
FROM
    foo1.dbo.member m
INNER JOIN  
    foo2.dbo.tbMembers mx ON m.headofhouse = mx.MemberID
WHERE   
    m.headofhouse NOT IN ('QESUB0000000190', 'QESUB0000000286',
                          'QESUB0000000308', 'QESUB0000000310',
                          'QESUB0000000315', 'QESUB0000000325',
                          'QESUB0000000330', 'QESUB0000001353',
                          'QESUB0000001367', 'QESUB0000001368')
    AND mx.MemberID = 100009
```

This script returns

```
headofhouse   MemberID
----------------------
100009        100009
```

I've tried a number of different approaches to replace the WHERE field NOT IN (value list), but nothing seems to work.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
    m.headofhouse,  mx.MemberID
FROM    
    foo1.dbo.member m
INNER JOIN  
    foo2.dbo.tbMembers mx ON m.headofhouse = mx.MemberID
WHERE   
    LEFT(m.headofhouse, 5) <> 'QESUB'       
    AND mx.MemberID = 100009
```

Error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'QESUB0000000190' to data type int.

I'm trying to understand why `WHERE fieldname NOT IN...` seems to behave differently than the rest of the `WHERE` clauses I've tried. Is there something special about the processing sequence of `NOT IN`? Or is there something else going on? Any troubleshooting tips would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the data type of column headofhouse?

Comment: as noted in the first paragraph, varchar(15)

Answer (score 1):

Do the comparison as strings:

```
FROM foo1.dbo.member m JOIN
     foo2.dbo.tbMembers mx 
     ON m.headofhouse = CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), mx.MemberID)
```

This might pose an issue if you have leading zeros on the `headofhouse`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a sub-query

```
SELECT  TOP 1000    
     m.headofhouse,   mx.MemberID
FROM  (
   SELECT headofhouse
   FROM foo1.dbo.member
   WHERE left(headofhouse,5) <> 'QESUB'
) m
INNER JOIN  foo2.dbo.tbMembers mx on m.headofhouse = mx.MemberID
WHERE mx.MemberID = 100009
```